# How do I promisify a callback from the goole.maps.places API getPlacePredictions?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to promisify a Google Maps API function, but seem not to succeed. I am getting a `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` when calling my function.

I tried to follow the examples in this thread, but no luck: [Turn callback into promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967065/turn-callback-into-promise)

The callback function would look like this:

```
predictionService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
predictionService.getPlacePredictions(
    { input: '1 main street, south bend' }, 
    displayPredictionSuggestionsCallback 
);

function displayPredictionSuggestionsCallback( input ){
    // output results
}
```

My promisifaction looks like this:

```
predictionService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

function getPredictionSuggestion ( input ){

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    predictionService.getPlacePredictions( { 
        input: input
    }, function (place, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            return dfd.reject("Request failed: " + status);
        }
        dfd.resolve( place ).promise();
    });
}
```

And this is the function that calls the service:

```
    getPredictionSuggestion( '1 main street, south bend' ).then( function(results) {
        console.log( 'promise results = ' + results );
    }, function( err ) {
        alert(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing most things right. Things to change:

1. You need to return the promise from your function. Add `return dfd.promise();` at the end.
2. You *don't* need `return` within your callback, just `else`.
3. You *don't* need `.promise()` on your `resolve` call.

So:

```
predictionService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

function getPredictionSuggestion ( input ){

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    predictionService.getPlacePredictions( { 
        input: input
    }, function (place, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            dfd.reject("Request failed: " + status); // ***
        } else {                                     // ***
            dfd.resolve( place );                    // ***
        }                                            // ***
    });

    return dfd.promise();                            // ***
}
```

---

That's for jQuery's `Deferred`. You might want to use native `Promise`instead, with a polyfill if needed:

```
predictionService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

function getPredictionSuggestion(input) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        predictionService.getPlacePredictions( { 
            input: input
        }, function (place, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                reject(new Error(status));
            } else {
                resolve(place);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Note the use of `new Error` with `reject`. In general, using `Error` with reject is useful because it provides context (where the "error" occurred).

Comment: You're a life savior.